# How can I equalize audio frequencies during video calls on MacOS?

Tags: macos, audio, equalizer

I am using MacOS Sonoma, and I have been experiencing discomfort in my ears during video calls on platforms like Zoom, Meet, Teams, and others. It seems that certain frequencies are causing this issue. Is there a way to equalize the sound during video calls on MacOS Sonoma to address this problem? Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

There's no native way to do it. You'd need something like [Rogue Amoeba's SoundSource](https://rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) which can do this either globally or per app.
It can use AU audio plugins either native from Apple [there are quite a few in macOS by default] or any 3rd party. The EQ shown below is Apple native.

[image]

No affiliation, merely a satisfied user.

Comment: Thanks, also, about so@oma typo fix :-)

Comment: Just curiosity, did you customize your EQ for my case? I guess is the setting I need.

Comment: No - that's to fix the horrible bass end on an M1 iMac, with just a hint of softening at 6kHz as well, which does smooth out the harshness a bit. ;))